# (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO email_logs (message_id,email_subject,from_address,to_address,email_html_content,email_content) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                    (message_id, subject, from_email_address, to_address, email_html_content, str(email_content)))
scrapper_email_id = cursor.lastrowid
print("scrapper_email_id: " + str(scrapper_email_id))
```

This is the sql query I have used but showing error (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))"). Is there any solution

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems with my connections to the Mysql Bank with this same error, and what I discovered in my case was that the way I opened and closed the connections was wrong, which allowed the connection to open until it expired, as my application was in the cloud, I had to keep deploying it again. What I did and solved my case was the following, as I am using the python library pymysql, I first created a function to call the connection string instead of always opening it at the beginning of the code, looking like this:

```py
def conectar_banco():

    return  pymysql.connect(host='IP ', 
                            user='root',
                            password='PSW',
                            database='BD',
                            port=3306 
                        )
```

The process of opening the connection was in the course of the code like this here

```
connpy = conectar_banco()
cursorpy = connpy.cursor()
cursorpy.execute(""")
data = cursorpy.fetchall()
```

finally closed the two that were opened

```
cursorpy.close()
connpy.close()
```

I know there are good practices for this but this solved my problem, I'm recently migrating to sqlalchemy which does this management very well